# What index do I need in Google Cloud Datastore to filter based on ID and another property?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-node

I use Google Cloud Datastore to store entities with a generated ID by Datastore as primary key.
In addition, I store other properties for each entity, in this example `owner`.

An entity looks like this in the Google Cloud Datastore Console:

```
|Name/ID             |owner           |...|
|id=5657437197565952 |5634472569470976|...|
```

I then want to filter entities based on the `key (id)` and the property `owner`.

To do this, I understand that I need a composite index to be able to filter on both fields (id) and owner at the same time. So I created a composite index using the following `index.yaml` file:

```
indexes:
- kind: job
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: __key__
  - name: owner

# AUTOGENERATED
```

The index shows up in the cloud console and if I filter on both fields using the cloud console UI it filters the correct entity in the table. The filter I do there is:

- Key is exactly as large as: `key(job,5657437197565952)`
- owner equals the string: `5634472569470976`

But when I try to retrieve this entity with the Node.js library by Google using the following code, I do not get any result:

```
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

async function quickStart() {
  const projectId = 'myproject';

  // Creates a client
  const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const keySelector = datastore.key(['myentity', '5657437197565952']);
  const query = datastore.createQuery('myentity').filter('key', keySelector).filter('owner', '=', '5634472569470976');

  const val = await query.run((err, entities, info) => {
    console.log(entities);
  });

  console.log('Got ' + val);
}
quickStart().catch(console.error);
```

The `entities` are empty and `val` is just the following if stringified:

```
[[],{"moreResults":"NO_MORE_RESULTS","endCursor":"CgA="}]
```

I also tried to create another index with the name `id` instead of `__key__` but had no luck.

My question is now: what composite index do I need to perform this filter on both fields so that the NodeJS code also retrieves the entity correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the key ID it is not necessary to bother with queries, filters and indexes anymore: there can be maximum one entity matching such query, which you can get by [direct key lookup](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity). I *think* would be something along these lines (sorry, I'm not node.js fluent):

```
const key = datastore.key(['myentity', 5657437197565952]);
const entity = await datastore.get(key);
```

A positive side effect is that key lookups are strongly consistent (queries are eventually consistent), see comparison table at [Eventual Consistency in Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#eventual-consistency-in-cloud-datastore).

But if you insist on filtering on the key then you'd have to reference the property using the special `__key__` name (as you did in your index file). From [Filters](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters):

> Key filters
>
> To filter on the value of an entity's key, use the special property
>   `__key__`:

In your case it'd be something like this:

```
const keySelector = datastore.key(['myentity', 5657437197565952]);
const query = datastore.createQuery('myentity')
                       .filter('__key__', '=', keySelector)
                       .filter('owner', '=', '5634472569470976');
```

**Note that the key `id` in the `keySelector` object creation needs to be without quotes!**

Comment: Thanks but what if I intentionally want filter on both the id and owner?

Comment: Thanks again for your edit, unfortunately this still does not work for me as it does not return the filtered entity. Is the composite index I created for this correct?

Comment: The index should be OK - otherwise your query would have failed with an missing index error. Try a query just with the key - make sure you have an entity.

Comment: Also check how many entries the index has: https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes

Comment: Thank you. With the help of your input I figured it out. I was first not able to retrieve the entity by only filtering on the `__key__`. The reason was, I created the `keySelector` object in the wrong format (I put the id number in quotes). Instead it needs to be `datastore.key(['myentity', 5657437197565952])`. Besides that, the index contained less entries than I have in the table itself so I recreated the entities in the table to have datastore recreate the index for those entities. Then the filter you mentioned (besides removing the quotes from the key id) worked.